# Convert text to Braille (Unicode) in Python

Tags: python

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_Patterns), the Unicode block for braille is U+2800 .. U+28FF.

I'm trying to convert normal text to Braille symbols (dots). To do so, I'm mapping this string:

```
" A1B'K2L@CIF/MSP\"E3H9O6R^DJG>NTQ,*5<-U8V.%[$+X!&;:4\\0Z7(_?W]#Y)="
```

The reason for mapping this specific string is mentioned [on this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_ASCII#Braille_ASCII_values)

My code:

```
def toBraille(c):
unic=2800
mapping = " A1B'K2L@CIF/MSP\"E3H9O6R^DJG>NTQ,*5<-U8V.%[$+X!&;:4\\0Z7(_?W]#Y)="
i = mapping.index(c.upper())
if (i>0):
    unic+=i 
    unichex = hex(unic)
    return unichr(unichex))
if (i==0):
    return '_'
if (i<O):
    return '?'

def converter(txt):
tmp=""
for x in txt:
    tmp+=str(toBraille(x))
return tmp

txt = raw_input("Please insert text: \n")
print(converter(txt))
```

I want to print braille characters like this

```
input = hello world
output = ⠓⠑⠇⠇⠕ ⠺⠕⠗⠇⠙
```

The problem is my output looks like this

```
Input = A
Output = 2801
```

Comment: Why are you mapping this string? What make is special w.r.t. your desired conversion? Do you expect your average colleague understand it?

Comment: I've read it on wikipedia [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_ASCII]: this C string (which can also be used in Python and other programming languages that accept C string literals) gives the Braille ASCII mappings for Unicode Braille characters U+2800 through U+283F in order, starting with U+2800 at the start of the string:

Comment: This is a rather counterintuitive encoding. One thing that breaks your code is 2800. It ought to be hexadecimal, 0x2800. Why not get rid of confusion and write a normal Python dictionary? `{'A':u'⠁',...}`?

Comment: Just create a dict that has the desired mapping and run each character through it.

Comment: @RadLexus Converting text to braille symbols

Comment: The oputput was like this [Input = A Output 2801]

Comment: @RadLexus Done.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/jpaugh/braille-converter and https://github.com/markomanninen/pybrl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remapping strings is built-in to python: with [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)  and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) you could do this:

```
intab = "helo"  # ...add the full alphabet and other characters
outtab = "⠓⠑⠇⠕" # and the characters you want them translated to
transtab = str.maketrans(intab, outtab)

strg = "hello"
print(strg.translate(transtab)) # ⠓⠑⠇⠇⠕
```

note that the length of `intab` must match the length of `outtab` if you pass 2 arguments to `maketrans` only (you could pass a third argument; see doc).

Comment: Note please this is Python 3 only. Translation tables are ascii only on python 2.

Answer (score 8):

Preferably, this should be defined as a dictionary, not as two arrays.

For Braille Dots:

```
code_table = {
    'a': '100000',
    'b': '110000',
    'c': '100100',
    'd': '100110',
    'e': '100010',
    'f': '110100',
    'g': '110110',
    'h': '110010',
    'i': '010100',
    'j': '010110',
    'k': '101000',
    'l': '111000',
    'm': '101100',
    'n': '101110',
    'o': '101010',
    'p': '111100',
    'q': '111110',
    'r': '111010',
    's': '011100',
    't': '011110',
    'u': '101001',
    'v': '111001',
    'w': '010111',
    'x': '101101',
    'y': '101111',
    'z': '101011',
    '#': '001111',
    '1': '100000',
    '2': '110000',
    '3': '100100',
    '4': '100110',
    '5': '100010',
    '6': '110100',
    '7': '110110',
    '8': '110010',
    '9': '010100',
    '0': '010110',
    ' ': '000000'}
```

Similarly can be done for [Braille Glyph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_ASCII#Braille_ASCII_values).

Answer (score 2):

I used a simple Python dictionary and it works but it's very basic

```
# ASCII
asciicodes = [' ','!','"','#','$','%','&','','(',')','*','+',',','-','.','/',
          '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',':',';','<','=','>','?','@',
          'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q',
          'r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','[','\\',']','^','_']

# Braille symbols
brailles = ['⠀','⠮','⠐','⠼','⠫','⠩','⠯','⠄','⠷','⠾','⠡','⠬','⠠','⠤','⠨','⠌','⠴','⠂','⠆','⠒','⠲','⠢',
        '⠖','⠶','⠦','⠔','⠱','⠰','⠣','⠿','⠜','⠹','⠈','⠁','⠃','⠉','⠙','⠑','⠋','⠛','⠓','⠊','⠚','⠅',
        '⠇','⠍','⠝','⠕','⠏','⠟','⠗','⠎','⠞','⠥','⠧','⠺','⠭','⠽','⠵','⠪','⠳','⠻','⠘','⠸']
```

Comment: this should be defined as dictionary not as two arrays. Current version is unmaintainable.

Comment: There are two issues problems with your answer that make it incorrect. Firstly, the minor issue is that the use of the lower case ascii symboles `'a'` through `'b'` is non-standard for (Braille Ascii)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_ASCII]; AsciiBraille is only defined for chars between `' '` and `'_'`. Secondly, `asciicodes[7]` is completely incorrect: it should be `'\''` not `''`. The correct asciicodes can trivially be generated using the following list comprehension: `[chr(i+32) for i in range(64)]`. Aside from those two mistakes this answer is fairly accurate.

Comment: For further clarification, the use of lowercase letter is only really a problem since the question is using a standard of Braille Ascii that explicitly makes use of chars `' '` to `'_'`. Other than that an the error made at `asiicodes[7]` this is an good response.