# How should i use braille alphabet in an array to draw an AsciiArt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, character, ascii, encode

This is my code

```
from PIL import Image

ASCII_CHARS = ["@", "#", "$", " ", " ", "-", "|", ":", ".", " ", " ", " " ]

def resize_image(image, new_width=50):
    width, height = image.size
    ratio = height/width
    new_height = int(new_width * ratio)
    resized_image = image.resize((new_width, new_height))
    #resized_image.save('output.png')
    return(resized_image)

def grayify(image):
    grayscale_image = image.convert("L")
    #grayscale_image.save('output.png')
    return(grayscale_image)

# convert pixels to a string of ascii characters
def pixels_to_ascii(image):
    pixels = image.getdata()
    characters = ''.join([ASCII_CHARS[pixel//25] for pixel in pixels])
    return(characters)

def main(new_width=50):
    # attempt to open image from user-input
    #path = input("Enter a valid pathname to an image:\n")
    try:
        image = Image.open("picachu.jpg")
    except:
        print(path, " is not a valid pathname to an image.")
        return

    # convert image to ascii
    new_image_data = pixels_to_ascii(grayify(resize_image(image)))

    # format
    pixel_count = len(new_image_data)
    ascii_image = '\n'.join([new_image_data[index:(index+new_width)] for index in range(0, pixel_count, new_width)])


    with open("full_image.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(ascii_image)

    fa = open("full_image.txt", "r")
    fb = open("trimmed_image.txt", "w")
    lines = fa.readlines()
    fa.close()
    lines = filter(lambda x: not x.isspace(), lines)
    fb.write("".join(lines))
    fb.close()

main()
```

and for picachu.jpg output is like this:

```
                             |-                   
                             $                    
                            |#$                   
                             ##.                  
 .:                         | #.                  
 :##  :                    ..:$.                  
  |### ..                  ...|.                  
   |## ..::.               :...                   
    :#$....::              :..:                   
     . |.....:.            :..:                   
       :|::...:.           ...:                   
         :|::..::::.:::.   ...:                   
          .:|:..........:....::                   
             ::...........::.:.                   
             :.............:.|                    
            ...:............::                    
            .. -:...........:.                    
            ..$$ ............                     
           .|.| |.......|:-..                     
           - ......::...  $.:                     
          .  :..:-  -...-#-.:                     
          :  :...   $ -......                     
          . -....--- $-....:: ..::                
           |:....||||-:...| -:....:               
           ......|||-:...:  |.....:               
            :....|--|....|  :....::               
         .::::::..||.....| |....:::::::...        
        :.......::.......:|....::..........::..   
       ..........::.....::....:|:..............:. 
       :.........:|::........:|:.:............... 
       ..........|:.........:| ..:::............  
        :::::::||:.........||  ..||||:.........   
         :|||||:..........:|   ::|||||::.....:    
          :::.............|    ::||::|||::..:     
          ................:   .::|.    .:|::      
          :................ |::.:|                
         .................: :|:.|.                
         .................: :||:|                 
         :..................: -                   
         :.................- $-                   
        ...................:  -                   
        :....................                     
        :....................                     
        :..........::::::...:                     
        .::::::::::||||||::..                     
         ||||||||||-||||||||.                     
        :::|||.     ..::|-|::|.                   
      .-|:::.            ...::-:                  
       ..                     ..
```

So there is no problem with the code! But the thing is that i want to use Braille alphabet "⡿⡾⡹⡲⡱⠶⠷⠸" instead of "@#|- etc"
and when i try :

```
ASCII_CHARS = ["\u280F", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
```

it gives me this error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u280f' in position 317: character maps to <undefined>`

**anyone have ideas how to solve this issue?**
you can find other Braille characters Unicode and Decimalcode [here](https://www.obliquity.com/computer/html/unicode2800.html)

Comment: Please give the full stack trace with your error message, showing the line where the error occurred.

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922629/convert-text-to-braille-unicode-in-python

Comment: Your terminal's encoding does not support braille characters, you need to configure it to support unicode. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line