# how do I replace a letter in word with another letter, or with a key from a dictionary

Tags: python

```py
def translate(phrase):
    translated_word = phrase
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter == "a":
            translated_word.replace(letter, "1", 1)
    print(translated_word)
         
            
print(translate(input("Enter: ")))

Output: None
```

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: ``translate`` does not return anything

Comment: this question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922629/convert-text-to-braille-unicode-in-python/41922947#41922947

Comment: @MikeScotty It doesn't return but print the output.

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav yes, I know, but ``print(translate(...))`` results in ``Output: None``.

Comment: @MikeScotty Oh!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can you write a str.replace() using dictionary values in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156473/can-you-write-a-str-replace-using-dictionary-values-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

```
def translate(phrase):
    translated_word = phrase
    translationDict = {
        'a': '1'
    }
    for k,v in translationDict.items():
        translated_word = translated_word.replace(k, v)
    return translated_word
         
            
print(translate('dupa'))
```

Comment: Good code. The answer would be even better if you added some explanation.

Comment: I must get used to explaining my code :), I always think it's self-explanatory

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure why you try to write a function to do that. The standard string method `replace()` already does what you want:

```
print(input("Enter: ").replace("a", "1"))
```

Note that the `replace()` method does *not* change the string (strings are immutable), but instead it returns a new string.